# How do I "update code" after removing <li> element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have 16 `<li>` items.
Upon clicking a button, I run the following code which removes a `<li>` item.

```
jQuery('.btnRemoveItem').live("click",function(){
    var obj = this;
    jQuery.post("wp-content/themes/storelocator/include/adm_gallery.php", { deleteImage: 'single', name: jQuery(this).attr('id') },
    function(data){
        if(data.status == 'deleted');
        {
            jQuery(obj).closest('li').fadeOut(400, function() { $(this).remove(); });
            var count = jQuery('#adminGallery ul li').length;
            jQuery('#imageCount').html(count);
        }
    }, "json");

});
```

This code works and removes the list item. However, doing a item count, still returns 16 items.
I therefore need to bind the event somehow. I thought maybe that `$.live` would help, but it has no effect.

How should I go around to "bind" the `<li>` removal?

Comment: Have you double-checked the HTML source before and after the removal? Firebug might help: getfirebug.com Also, when and how are you performing the item count?

Comment: Never mind the second question - I just realized I hadn't read your code carefully enough. However, I've found the `.html()` method a little glitchy at times - try using `.text()` instead and see if it's just that it's not updating the number correctly.

Comment: `.html()` works. I've checked by using `.html('10')`.  By doing an `alert(count)`, I get the number 16, and not 15 as it should be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not working because you are not removing the element until it finishes fading out which takes 400ms, meanwhile the rest of the code moves on and the count still sees the soon-to-be-deleted `<li>`.

Simply move the two lines below the fadeout to be inside the callback function and it will work as you intend.

Comment: When coding all day, sometimes you see yourself blind on your own code. This worked perfectly. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a simpler approach would work:

```
jQuery('#imageCount').html(count - 1);
```

What you have doesn't work because the element isn't actually removed until it has finished fading out.

Comment: +1 Yup, dicovered that :) Using @Paolos solution worked great :)